# Is there any light sequencing software?

Tags: music

I would like to sequence a number of stage lights that will change synchronously to a song. 
Is there any tool that would help me to do that? Even if it only sequences virtual lights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of free dmx-[donation]
http://www.chromakinetics.com/DMX/
Pay for.
VenueMagic
http://www.brothersoft.com/venuemagic-139627.html
Lumidesk
http://www.lumidesk.com/
Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen a free tool, however, most [DMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMX512) panles usually come with a free basic utility needed to manage the lights.

If you pay a little more, there are many tools out there that let you time and sequence a light show, along with a virtual set that you can mess around with.

One software that I know of is [Martin Light Jockey](http://www.martin.com/product/product.asp?product=lightjockey) - but I don't think it is cheap!